# Error in c++: the function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

So I'm very new to c++ and I was trying to make a currency converter from pln to either usd or euros. However I keep getting the error written in the title of this post. How do you suggest I fix it and what did I write wrong in this code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace a std;


int main()
{
  cout<<"Welcome to my currency converter program! There are currently two choices of currency to convert to from PLN: euros (€) and us dollars ($). \n\n";
  int pln;
  int total;
  string convertcurrency;
  cout<<"Please input the amount of PLN you'd like to convert. ";
  cin >> pln;
  cout<<"Which currency would you like to convert " << pln << "PLN to? (euros/dollars) ";
  cin >> convertcurrency;
  /*cout << Euc_ver2(a, b);
  return 0;*/
  cout << "Converting " << pln << "PLN to " << convertcurrency << ". . . \n";
  cout << converting(total) << convertcurrency;
  return 0;
}

int converting(string convertcurrency, int pln, int total)
{
    if (convertcurrency=="dollars")
        total = pln * 0.22;
    else
        total = pln * 0.25;
    return total;
}
```

The aim of this program is to get an input from the user saying how much pln they wish to convert and to which currency. Then the program prints the final converted amount in the selected currency

Comment: Add a function declaration for the converting function. Put the following line: `int converting(string convertcurrency, int pln, int total);` before `int main() {`

Comment: `using namespace a std;` typo??

Comment: Hard to typo `using namespace std;` if you don't use it in the first place. [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)